# Listening to multiple value of checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery hook-on that listens for a checkbox with the name `wantProdTy` that has the values "Mobile" or "Broadband". How should i write this?

Checkbox with value "Mobile":

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="wantProdTy"][value="Mobile"]').change(function() {
    // do something
}
```

**EDIT**
Accepted answer:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="wantProdTy"]').filter(function(){
        return /(Mobile|Broadband)/i.test(this.value);
    }).change(function() {
        <% // check that the checkbox is checked %>
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            <% // check that mobile or broadband has not reached the maximum limit %>
            maximumServiceLimitListener();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `filter`:

```
$('input[name=wantProdTy]').filter(function(){
  return /(mobile|broadband)/i.test(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to do it at the selector level?

Comment: Does it mean that if it is not mobile or broadband, the function will return. Otherwise it will continue?

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on a group of your checkboxes and listen for that:

```
$(".myCheckboxClass").change(function(){
    // do something
});
```